# How to write JPA query with boolean condition

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpql, jpa-2.0

In my project i am using JPA 2.0 with eclipselink inplementation, an I have following problem:

I have defined entity with boolean column:

```
@Entity
public User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USR_ID")
    private Short id;

    @Column(name="USR_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="USR_ACTIVE")
    private boolean active;

    .......

}
```

I want to create query which will return all active users, something like this:

*select u from User u where u.active = TRUE;*

But if I use that query I got exception that boolean can't be cast to Short (column in database is stored as smallint). Is there any correct way how to write this query?

Thanks

Comment: What JPA provider are you using (i.e. Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA, etc)? What database vendor are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)? What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipselink as JPA provider, Derby as database and Derby client jdbc driver, but also Spring for creation of EntityManager, transaction managment... And there was also a problem, i have forget to specified JPA vendor. After adding <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>  query with TRUE condition works.

Comment: Have the same here with Derby/Hibernate. But it works for MySQL though. :-)

Answer (score 44):

Use the following form:

```sql
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.active = TRUE
```

See [the docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL) for more info.

Comment: the answer is "SELECT e FROM  Employee e WHERE e.active = TRUE",you can ignore the link. So It is not a " Link-only answers"! Furthermore ，link can be invalid so does any answer! So the link is a reference for anybody who is interesting to read more. Last but not least, the link is a wiki link ,so it's no less than an answer but a method to get what you want to know!!!

Comment: Wow,if the answer is wrong ,you just can add your comment. And then it will be useful to recognize that the link had been out-of-date. Don't know what the downvotes means really.

Answer (score 4):

For MySql works this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {    
    @Query("SELECT e FROM  Employee e WHERE e.active=?1")
    User findByStatus(Boolean active);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too (PostgreSQL + Eclipselink) and got it working with the `@TypeConverter` and `@Convert` annotations.

```
@Entity
@TypeConverter(name = "booleanToInteger", dataType = Integer.class)
public User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USR_ID")
    private Short id;

    @Column(name="USR_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="USR_ACTIVE")
    @Convert("booleanToInteger")
    private boolean active;

    .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using EclipseLink as JPA provider and a MySQL database. With this configuration, using 1 for true and 0 for false works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  @TypeConverter(dataType=Integer.class)

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like :

@Query("SELECT u from User u order by u.active");

It will display inactive users first. If you want to see active user first use like :

@Query("SELECT u from User u order by u.active desc");

Answer (score 0):

It's working in my scenerio:

```
findByTitleAndDocumentIdAndIsDeleted(String title, UUID docId, Boolean isDeleted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways in the example, first one with the flag already set on method, the other is parametric/parametrized:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_metadata")
@Data 
public class TdMetadata {

    @Column
    private Boolean isCalculated;
}


@Repository
public interface TdMetadataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TdMetadata, Integer> {

    List<TdMetadata> findByCalculatedTrue();
    List<TdMetadata> findByCalculated(Boolean calculated);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

TRUE is a special keyword.
try

> select u from User u where u.active IS TRUE;

Comment: "u.active IS TRUE" did not work for me either, but "u.active = TRUE" did. Working with EclipseLink 2.5