# Build WHERE clause dynamically based on filter in queryDSL

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a query that needs a dynamic SQL `WHERE` clauses based on filters.

#### Issue

It may give me a *NullPointerException* (NPE) if I'm adding an `"AND"` while the previous filter is not existing.

#### Code

```
public List<BlocageDeblocageCompte> getMyQuery(FiltersDTO filters) {

    JPAQuery<MY_ENTITY> myEntity = getJPAQueryFactory().selectFrom(myEntity).limit(20);
    BooleanExpression whereClause = null;

    boolean whereClauseAdded = false;
    boolean ifNoFilter = Stream.of(myEntity).allMatch(Objects::isNull);

    if (ifNoFilter) {
        return new ArrayList<>(myEntity.fetchAll().fetch());
    }
            
    if (filters.getId() != null) {
        whereClause = myEntity.id.eq(filters.getId());
        whereClauseAdded = true;
    }

    if (filters.getName() != null) {
        if (whereClauseAdded) {
            whereClause = whereClause.and(myEntity.id.eq(filters.getName()));
        } else {
            whereClause = myEntity.id.eq(filters.getName());
            whereClauseAdded = true;
        }
    }

    // remaining code
}
```

#### Question

Is there a better way to add the filters, without risking a NPE?

Answer (score 1):

To construct complex boolean queries like this you can use [`com.querydsl.core.BooleanBuilder`](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/5.0.0/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/BooleanBuilder.html):

```java
public List<MyEntity> getMyQuery(FiltersDTO filters) {
    MyEntity myEntity = QModel.myEntity;

    // build an optional WHERE clause with predicates using AND conjunctions 
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

    if (filters.getId() != null) {
        builder.and(myEntity.id.eq(filters.getId()));   
    }
    
    if (filters.getName() != null) {
        builder.and(myEntity.id.eq(filters.getName()));   
    }
    
    // construct the query
    return getJPAQueryFactory().selectFrom(myEntity)
        .limit(20)
        .where(builder)  // myEntity.id eq id1 AND myEntity.name eq name1
        .fetch();            
}
```

#### See also

Similar questions:

- [Dynamic search term SQL query with Spring JPA or QueryDSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598374/dynamic-search-term-sql-query-with-spring-jpa-or-querydsl/61599367#61599367)
- [JPA QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183329/jpa-querybuilder)
- [How to write JPA query with boolean condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251054/how-to-write-jpa-query-with-boolean-condition)

References:

- QueryDSL Reference Guide: [3.1.1. Complex predicates](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch03.html#d0e2053)
- QueryDSL Issue on GitHub: [BooleanBuilder with multiple AND conditions · Discussion #2936](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/discussions/2936)
- Baeldung's Tutorial: [A Guide to Querydsl with JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/querydsl-with-jpa-tutorial)

Comment: @Abdel Here at SO we use votes to say "Thank You" or mark helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `Specification` interface in JPA:

1. first of all, create a `Filter` class with static predicate-methods to handle fields in WHERE clause:

```java
public class Filter{

    public static Specification<BlocageDeblocageCompte> hasName(String name) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            if (name == null || name.equals("")) {
                 return cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true)); // always true = no filtering
            }
            return cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + name + "%");
        };
    }

    public static Specification<ActiveAlarm> hasId(Integer id) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            if (id == null) {
                return cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true)); // always true = no filtering
            }
            return cb.equal(root.get("id"), id);
        };
    }
}
```

2. then, use the `Filter` class in your methods:

```
repository.findAll(where(Filter.hasName(filters.getName()).and(Filter.hasId(filters.getId()));
```

For more details, see:

- Baeldung:
  [REST Query Language with Spring Data JPA Specifications](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)
- Spring blog: [Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)
- Kailas Nath on Medium: [Using JPA Specification Interface To Implement Dynamic Filters](https://medium.com/cleartax-engineering/using-jpa-specification-interface-to-implement-dynamic-filters-ea5d022b67f1)
- DZone: [Java: Using the Specification Pattern With JPA](https://dzone.com/articles/java-using-specification)

Comment: you right.i edited my answer

Answer (score -1):

I found out a simple solution, when we do WHERE on all of them it transform automatically the second where to AND. thank u guys.

```
    JPAQuery<MyEntity> myEntityJPAQUERY=
            getJPAQueryFactory()
                    .selectFrom(QmyEntity);
    
    if (filtresDTO.getId() != null) {
        myEntityJPAQUERY=myEntityJPAQUERY.where(QmyEntity.id.eq(ffiltresDTO.getId()));

    if (filtresDTO.getName() != null) {
myEntityJPAQUERY=myEntityJPAQUERY.where(QmyEntity.name.eq(ffiltresDTO.getName()))
    }
```

Comment: Please show your solution (as code) - [example] with explanation. This is not an answer that helps other fellows which have similar issues.

Comment: What are `QmyEntity`, `ffiltresDTO` and `QmyEntity`, where defined ? Still not a [example], please also pay attention to proper formatting.